# pagination not working on SEO URls opencart 2.1.x

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, pagination, opencart2.x

Hi am facing an issue with pagination on Opencart when SEO URLs in setting is enabled.

I am using oepncart `v2.1.x`. below option is used for SEO [image]

And to make URLs SEO i make entry for product SEO URL while adding product like as below 
[image]

But with this pagination is not working at all. I am getting URL directly as

> http://example.com/dfgfd-dfgfdg

and when i disable SEO option then i get URL as

> http://example.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=61_71&page=1

It is woking when SEO is disabled. Any ideas please?

I have installed extenstion `super_seo.xml` by `orestius` to make other URLs SEO like registration and login URLs.

Comment: When you enable seo, does your pagination work or not?

Comment: no .. that is what i have writtem

Comment: This is a bug. There are extensions available for this.

Comment: I have mentioned an extension in qustion. you please let me know if any

Comment: and i get error lke 2016-04-20 12:16:34 - PHP Notice:  Undefined index: query in /home/folder/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_storage_modification_catalog_controller_common_seo_url.php on line 90

Comment: there is error in the file `system/storage/modification/catalog/controller/common/seo_url.php`

Comment: And how to solve this?? Can you provide me seo url php file

Comment: I'm afraid this comes with the extension. By default we don't have it.

Comment: Ah!! Here is the point. So would you like to suggest some extensions here that i can use. Obviously free ones

Comment: Or will it be a good idea to use scroll loading products instead of pagination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting this as answer as it freaked me to hell from last 2-3 days. I have figured out a code and can be made as below as a change:

**Only tested on OC 2.1.x**

1. find **catalog/controller/common/seo_url.php**
2. Use code mentioned here [Here](http://shorttext.com/77c5859e) {if link does not work in future, feel free to mail me for same}
3. open **index.php** in root folder and make entry

   ```
   $controller->addPreAction(new Action('common/seo_url'));
   ```
4. Go to your DB and find table **url_alias** and make entry in table as in below image

[image]

By following above 4 steps everything works like charm and Pagination works perfectly now even with SEO URLs.

Eg. Url will look like as below:

```
http://example.com/index.php?route=account/logout
will become http://example.com/logout
```

and Pagination will be

```
http://example.com/example-collection?page=2
```